# Realm in Swift one to many relation

Tags: swift, realm

I just recently started developing in Swift and Realm. I have an realm objects that look like this:

```
 class PersonItem: Object
 {
   dynamic var Id = ""
   dynamic var Name = ""
   dynamic var LastName = ""
 }
 class PersonDetailsItem: Object
 {
   dynamic var Id = ""
   dynamic var JobDescription = ""
   var ImagesArray = List<ImageItem>()
 }
```

Another that looks like this:

```
 class ImageItem: Object
 {
   dynamic var base64String = ""
 }
```

I have a list of person items displayed in a tableView. On didSelectItemAtIndexPath i call a method to fetch details for every item. Now when i recieve data from server i get an array of images base64 encoded. I am trying to save them in the Images list so i can retrieve them offline, and i can't seem to get that to work. This is one of the things i tried

```
try! realm.write{
for obj in self.imagesArray //the array with the images from server
{
    let image = ImageItem()
    image.base64String = obj as! String
    personDetailsItem.ImagesArray.append(image)
} 

let items = realm.objects(PersonDetailsItem)
if items.count > 0
{
    for obj in items
    {
       if obj.valueForKey("Id") as? String == personItem.Id
       {
         realm.add(personDetailsItem, update: true)
         return
       }
     }
     realm.add(personDetailsItem)
     }
     else
     {
        realm.add(personDetailsItem)
     }
 }
```

The result: In all the items are saved the images from the first item i open. What am i missing here? Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well i should put my foot in my mouth :). The problem wasn't the way i was writing them, it was in the way i was reading them. The code works but i ended up using a different solution a more clear one:

```
  try! realm.write
  {
       for obj in self.imagesArray
       {
          let image = ImageItem()
          image.base64String = obj as! String
          personDetailsItem.imagesArray.append(image)
       }
       if realm.objectForPrimaryKey(PersonDetailsItem.self, key: personDetailsItem.Id) == nil
       {
          realm.add(personDetailsItem)
       }
       else
       {
          realm.add(personDetailsItem, update: true)
       }
   }
```

If anybody has something to add please do. Thanks